# User ID in AIR application

Tags: android, ios, flash, air

is it possible to use a sort of 'user id' inside an AIR application? In my app every user can create and save pictures, but I need the possibility to exchange pictures between users. So, every pictures need to have, in the name, some code related to the user that creates the image (like xxxx_1.jpg, xxx_2.jpg where xxx is the user id).

My AIR app is for iOS and Android

Any idea???

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Will be necessary to get the device ID and save as key for your user database table. So, you can use the 'userDeviceID'_1.jpg, 'userDeviceID'_2.jpg…

You can try this [native extension](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-DeviceId) (works fine for iOS and Android) to get the device ID.

Based on Josh Janusch's comment 'Apple has removed the UDID API from iOS 7', so, try to follow [this tutorial](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)
I'm going to test it to be sure that really works.

Comment: Apple has removed the UDID API from iOS 7 after deprecating it in iOS 5 or 6. You no longer have access to the ID, so that is not a viable suggestion.